# reddit-like sorting in rethinkdb

Tags: rethinkdb

I'm using rethinkdb with the [thinky](http://thinky.io/) ORM on node.js.

I'm trying to sort documents (posts, comments) from a rethinkdb table using a function that takes data from documents, and outputs a number that represents the sorting index of each document, much like [reddit's time-sensitive ranking algorithm](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/master/r2/r2/lib/db/_sorts.pyx#L45-L56). The data should then be able to be paginated using `.slice()`.

Does anyone know how to do this? I'm completely lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReQL's `orderBy` term can take a function and order by its result.

I'm not certain about the exact syntax in Thinky (it should be similar), but this is how you would do it in plain ReQL:

```
r.table(...).orderBy(function (row) { return row('sorting_index'); })
```

The function `function (row) { return row('sorting_index'); }` is just an example. You can use any ReQL function, or even `r.js()` to supply an arbitrary JavaScript function http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/js/. Be aware though that `r.js()` is usually a lot slower than using native ReQL statements.

The documentation for `orderBy` has a complete example for this: http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/order_by/

If you run this query often and performance is important (or the data set is large), I recommend creating a secondary index to speed this operation up:

```
r.table(...).indexCreate("sorting_idx", function (row) { return row('sorting_index'); })
```

Then you can use:

```
r.table(...).orderBy({index: "sorting_idx"})
```